# Copy text from DIV by clicking button

Tags: jquery

How to make "Copy button", that will copy all texts from :

```
<div id="x">
<span id="text">text</span>
<span id="info">text</span>
....
</div>
```

to **clipboard**

Comment: "Copy" as in move to another element? Or to clipboard? Or where?

Comment: what info, you meant the text inside the spans or the number of elements it have etc?

Comment: To the user's clipboard? Also, what content exactly are you wanting to copy?

Comment: updated (all texts from span's to user clipboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i believe this is possible, is by communicating with Flash via JavaScript. You're not able to access these things with just JavaScript for security reasons.

http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a loop at this jQuery plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

There doesn't seem to be a native way to do this and all of the code samples I've looked at, including the plugin above, all seem a bit sketchy.

In IE it's possible to use some IE native code to do the copy but for other browsers there's a reliance on Flash, which, as of version 10 seems to impliment further restrictions on this action.